# asp code to get new data every new day

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am new to dynamic web apps, hence asking for help may be on some basic thing. I need to display some data on a clients website (untill now static). That data is nothing but few words of simple text. The catch is every new day a new row should get displayed on the page.

Technologies to use ASP.Net 4.0, VB.Net, SQL Server...

Can any of my fiend here guide me how to do this, very help ful would be if some one provide me asp,VB,SQL code for it.

Thanks

Comment: Try something and get back here.

Comment: Come on guys, be nice. Obviously he is newbie and is not asking for the code, only for guidance...

Comment: It is strongly encouraged by the community that you include some code in your questions here (what you have attempted so far).  This is mentioned in the faq, and in the "how to ask" page that you have to click through when asking a question as a new user (both of which you should read through if you have not done so).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to implement something like this in aspx page:

```
<% DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy"); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics but will try to help. The way I would do it is diving your app in two different parts.

- **First part**: Its responsibility would be **presenting the information**. You create an app that shows in the website the data from a DB. You should use here ASP.NET & Vb.net or C# (My personal recommendation is try to avoid vb.net but this is up to you) to connect to a SQL Server.
- **Second part**: Its responsibility would be **updating db**. You have to manage yourself to have this db refreshed somehow. If your original data is updated in a daily basis you have two options here. Or the data push into your db or your code pull the data.

  - **Push Data**: If you have control over data source you can modify it somehow and make data source to update your db. Ideally this should be done as soon as data is updated. If not, it can be updated in a daily basis. Depend of your problem details
  - **Pull Data**: If you don't have control then you can have a console app launched by a scheduled task (as often as you need it) that reads from data source and updates db.

Comment: why to avoid vb.net ?

Comment: It is just a recommendation. C# is the main language of .net and vb.net was introduced only to help catching previous vb6 programmers. At the moment you can use vb.net or c# but who knows if in the future vb.net will be still there. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507291/should-we-select-vb-net-or-c-sharp-when-upgrading-our-legacy-applications

Comment: I don't think you should be recommending C# over VB.NET, especially on a question tagged VB.NET (and not C#). You could argue that C# was only introduced to catch previous Java programmers! Apart from that recommending a console app running on a scheduled task as a solution to a web application question makes my eyes bleed.

Comment: wow! I love flame wars. I recommended C# and got a downvote from a vb.net fan. I think I can recommend whatever I think is better as far as I let be clear that can be achieved with both. :-)

Comment: Anyways I have edited answer to make it clearer for @Mona Kapoor. Thanks.

Comment: My downvote is for the second part of your answer as I don't see this as a good solution.

Comment: Fair enough (I thought your pet was angry with me). Updated to cover the other scenario instead of assuming he has no control over data source.

Answer (score 0):

Two options: (C# implemented, modify the code behind to VB if you wish)

1. Code behind: `public string MyMethod()
       {
           return "Hello!";
       }`

   ASPX: `<%= MyMethod()%>`
2. Code behind: `public void MyMethod()
   {
       MyText.Text = "Hello!";
   }`

   ASPX: `<asp:Label ID="MyText" runat="server"></asp:Label>`

**This way you can modify the message ('Hello!') to something dynamic**.